# AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE for Google API's

Tags: java, android, google-data-api

Okay, so I know how to get a list of accounts so that I can let the user authenticate my app to use with their Google Data, however, I am confused on what to use for my `AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE`.

Here is the current code that I have:

```
AccountManager.get(this).getAuthTokenByFeatures("com.google", AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, null, this, null,null)
```

I don't know where to find the `AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE` for the Picasa API that I want to use (along with all the other Google API's). Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE is the OAuth scope for the API, to be used. For account manager to understand that it is an OAuth2.0 you need to append it by "oauth2:". So for example for tasks API it will look something like this.

```
String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks";
```

And for picasa it will be

```
String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "oauth2:https://picasaweb.google.com/data/"
```

**EDIT:** Some of the Google APIs provide use of special alias strings in place of writing entire OAuth2 scope. For example [here](http://code.google.com/apis/tasks/oauth-android-auth-token-type-aliases.html) is the AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE alias for the Google Tasks API.

Comment: Beautiful, this is exactly the concept I needed to explore to figure out my answer for this project.