# What auth_token_type to use for Drive?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Just like the poster of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708638/auth-token-type-for-google-apis) question, I am confused about google api scopes.

I would like full access to the Drive API. I request a token like this:

```
private static final String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
accountManager.getAuthToken(account, AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, null, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
...
```

However I always get a screen telling me "Couldn't sign in. A problem occurred while communicating with Google servers. Please try again later."

Of course I made sure that internet access through the browser is working normally.

Also, I don't see any difference with what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759432/android-app-acquire-access-token-for-google-drive-api) guy did, who has no problems.

And last, in the second post I mentioned, user Nivco confirms that the use of Drive API is quite limited. Can someone confirm that I cannot create files or set permissions? If this is the case, this api has no value for me.

NOTE: I don not use any options, which seem to be used in the second post I mentioned. But I don't know which are available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried again with the same device a day later, and everything seems all right. So either the server refused me because of too many failed attempts, or the cached key in device memory was still being used...

Comment: So... how can this be debugged?

Comment: You might try first getting a token and then passing that to invalidateToken to force the accountManager to request a new one. But I think waiting a day is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question, you can create files and set permissions (and do many other things) with the Drive API v2:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

Just note that the API has multiple scopes you can request and what you can do with the API varies according to them.